# Follow the Clicks

Tags: jquery, click

Whenever you click the page, the heading should move to the
click location.

```
 <body>
            <h1>Hola Mi Gente, Comó estas!</h1>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
            <script>
                
                    $("html").click(function(event){
                        $("#heading").offset({
                            left: event.pageX,
                            top: event.pageY
                        });
                    })
                
            </script>
        </body>
```

Comment: When I run this code nothing happens.

Comment: Did you give `position` as `absolute` to the `h1`?

Comment: Typo.  There's no `#heading` element.  Did you mean to add that `id` to your `<h1>`?  Or to select the `$('h1')` instead?

Comment: @RhondaMckenney Have a look at my snippet and answer.  It works.

Comment: Thank you everyone that took the time to answer. @David, you were right, I had a typo. I did not have the id"heading" in my h1 tag.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman, thank you, I will certainly use your example as well when I use css with html, and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give `position` as `absolute` to the `<h1>` tag. Also, use `.css()` instead of `.position()`. That will most probably solve it and give `id="heading"` to `<h1>` tag:

```js
$(function() {
  $("html").click(function(event) {
    $("#heading").css({
      left: event.pageX,
      top: event.pageY
    });
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#heading {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  background: #cfc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="heading">Hola Mi Gente, Comó estas!</h1>
```